# Why are the images flashing?

Tags: jquery, css

On this page `http://128.199.58.229/landingpage/` Each image is coded like

```
<span class="tribeimg">
<img src="images/tribes/img.jpg">
<p class="lt-tribe-name">Tribe Name</p>
</span>
```

My CSS looks like

```
.tribeimg img {
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.tribeimg .lt-tribe-name {
opacity: 0.7;
z-index: 11;
color: white;
position: absolute;
left: 32px;
bottom: 50px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 8px black;
}
```

I'm using Jquery to fadeTo different opacity.

```
$(document).delegate('.tribeimg', 'mouseover', function() {
    $(this).children('img').fadeTo(333, 1);
    $(this).children('.lt-tribe-name').fadeTo(333, 1);
});

$(document).delegate('.tribeimg', 'mouseout', function() {
    $(this).children('img').fadeTo(333, 0.7);
    $(this).children('.lt-tribe-name').fadeTo(333, 0.7);
});
```

This kind of works. But on mouseout sometimes the images flash. Try moving the mouse quickly around to exaggerate the flashing. Not sure why? I just want a single fade in and fade out.

How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Demo is at the URL at the top of the question: http://128.199.58.229/landingpage

Comment: why are you using the `delegate` function? it's deprecated and it's better practice to use the `on` function instead

Comment: Thanks updated from 'delegate' to 'on'. I got that function from another stackoverflow question.. must have been from a while back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).delegate('.tribeimg', 'mouseover', function() {
    $(this).children('img').stop(true,true).fadeTo(333, 1);
    $(this).children('.lt-tribe-name').stop(true, true).fadeTo(333, 1);
});

$(document).delegate('.tribeimg', 'mouseout', function() {
    $(this).children('img').stop(true, true).fadeTo(333, 0.7);
    $(this).children('.lt-tribe-name').stop(true, true).fadeTo(333, 0.7);
});
```

Replace your jQuery code with this... It will solve your problem.

Comment: No, it won't. Setting both arguments to true makes the animation jump immediately to its end. This behavior will definitely *not* look nice.

Answer (score 1):

They flash because you don't stop the animation.

Try

```
$(document).delegate('.tribeimg', 'mouseout', function() {
    $(this).children('img').stop().fadeTo(333, 0.7);
    $(this).children('.lt-tribe-name').stop().fadeTo(333, 0.7);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you hover over the image it adds the fadeTo event to an event queue.

Stop the on going event with stop() so that the events don't stack up giving you the flashing effect.

```
$(this).children('img').stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin to prevent this behaviour, or use [jquery stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)